# Logging framework for iOS

Tags: ios, framework, logs

Is there an Objective-C framework for logging?

Ideally it would be similar to this separated pair of [Façade API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) & implementation-or-adapter:

- [**Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)**](http://www.slf4j.org/)
  The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging, logback, log4j) allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.
- [**Logback project**](http://logback.qos.ch)
  Natively implements the SLF4J API

Would be nice if various modules could plugin to send log messages to email, REST web services, and other alternate routes as well as local text files.

I am *not* asking about capturing crashes and stack traces. Just managing logging messages.

Comment: Similar on StackOverflow: [Logging Framework for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3130614/642706)